# Knowledge of restrictions over multiple tables to return information

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm having some trouble with how to construct a relation.

- A `Foo` has many `Bar`s, a `Bar` can have many `Foo`s
- A `Foo` has many `Zaz`s, a `Zaz` can have many `Foo`s
- A `Bar` can have many `Zaz`s and a `Zaz` can have one `Bar`

  - A `Bar` can only have one `Zaz` per `Foo`

So for example I should be able to do the following (assuming only one element in each type for simplicity):

```
// get a single Foo
Foo foo = this.Session.Get<Foo>(1);
// get a single Bar
Bar bar = this.Session.Get<Bar>(1);
// no restriction on Foo so get a collection
IEnumerable<Zaz> allZazsInFoo = foo.Zazs;
// no restriction on Bar so get a collection
IEnumerable<ZaZ> allZazsInBar = bar.Zazs;
// restriction on Foo by Bar so only one Zaz
Zaz zazOfABarInFoo = foo.Bars.Single().Zaz;
// restriction on Bar by Foo so only one Zaz
Zaz zazOfAFooInBar = bar.Foos.Single().Zaz;
```

Does this make sense? Is this form of relationship  (or something similar) possible in NHibernate?

Comment: I like the question because of complexity, but is this focused on creating the schema in such a way that the database enforces it or _simply_ that NHiberate takes care of it?

Comment: @M.Mimpen I don't think the database needs to enforce anything special here. I __think__ (correct me if I'm wrong) it should just be a `M:M` on `Foo:Bar`, a `M:M` on `Foo:Zaz` and a `1:M` on `Bar:Zaz`. So it's more just getting NHibernate to play nicely so it makes sense in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, what I went for in the end was actually stupidly easy.

In the `Foo` class I added:

```
public virtual Zaz GetZaz(int barId)
{
    return this.Zazs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Bar.Id == barId);
}
```

Then call like so:

```
Bar aBarInFoo = foo.Bars.Single();
Zaz zazOfABarInFoo = foo.GetZaz(aBarInFoo.Id);
```